# Is there a single word for "landlocked" as in "a landlocked country" in Portuguese?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia

I can think of **"sem litoral"**, **"cercado por terras"**, or **"sem acesso ao mar"** but I'm looking for a single word.

My curiosity was aroused as I was reading that there are only two doubly-landlocked countries in the world: Liechtenstein and Uzbekistan, which means not only are they landlocked, but their surrounding countries are also landlocked.
I'm trying to find the right words to say that in Portuguese. "*Esses países são 'duplamente sem litoral'*", "*duplamente cercados por terras*", or "*duplamente sem acesso ao mar*..." all sound awkward and very confusing.

**Is there a word or two that could complete "São países duplamente_______" and convey exactly what I'm trying to?**

Comment: A little bit out of scope, but it's incredible that only 2 countries, among hundreds, are double land-locked. I had to check a map to believe! Can you share your source for this claim?

Comment: @gmauch https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landlocked_country

Comment: I believe *duplamente encravados* would work just fine here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Português (English below)

Um país sem acesso ao mar é um ***país interior***, e podemos dizer que o Liechtenstein e o Uzbequistão são países duplamente interiores. Esta aceção de *interior* vem no Aulete e no Priberam:

> [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/interior): **3** Cercado de terras ou continentes (mar interior).
>   [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/interior): **2.** Situado entre terras ou rodeado por terra (ex.: mar interior).

Ambos os dicionários dão *mar interior* como exemplo, mas o conceito é o mesmo quando aplicado a países. E encontramos vários exemplos na literatura. Este [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/) tem doze exemplos de *país interior*, duma enciclopédia que não identifica. Por exemplo:

> O Paraguai é um ***país interior*** situado na América do Sul

Alguns exemplos identificados:

> Localizado na África central, o Ruanda é um ***país interior*** e não tem acesso imediato ao cabo de fibra submarino. [[*Perspectivas Económicas na África*, 
>   OECD, African Development Bank, 2009.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=_LUKRs5yKvcC&pg=PT94&dq=%22pa%C3%ADs%20interior%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiutrOOiNTLAhUEWhQKHcHdDbc4ChDoAQgpMAI#v=onepage&q=%22pa%C3%ADs%20interior%22&f=false)
>
> Niger [...] Situaçao geográfica: ***país interior***, cortado a oeste pelo rio que lhe da o nome [[Murillo Alves da Cunha, ‎J. Michaelovitch, *Atlas Mundial*, 1968.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=pOBKAAAAYAAJ&q=%22pa%C3%ADs%20interior%22&dq=%22pa%C3%ADs%20interior%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjci6mbitTLAhWHbxQKHd4QDlY4MhDoAQhGMAg)
>
> Desde a viagem de Vasco da Gama à Índia, em 1498, que se sabia que a Etiópia era um ***país interior***, onde se poderia chegar a partir de alguns portos do Mar Vermelho controlados pelos muçulmanos. [[André Ferrand de Almeida, «Da Demanda do Preste João à Missão Jesuíta na Etiópia», *Lusitânia Sacra*, 2ª Série, Tomo XI, 1999, p.264.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=G7OwHFo6CVIC&pg=PA264&dq=%22pa%C3%ADs%20interior%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv1Oy2jNTLAhWFXRQKHU52C-U4HhDoAQgvMAM#v=onepage&q=%22pa%C3%ADs%20interior%22&f=false)

---

### English

A *landlocked country* is in Portuguese a ***país interior***, and we can say the doubly landlocked Liechtenstein and Uzbekistan are *países duplamente interiores*. We can fin this meaning of *interior* in Aulete and Priberam:

> [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/interior): **3** Cercado de terras ou continentes (mar interior). [Surrounded by land or continents (landlocked sea).]
>   [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/interior): **2.** Situado entre terras ou rodeado por terra (ex.: mar interior). [Located amid lands or surrounded by land (ex.: landloked sea).]

Both dictionaries give *mar interior* (landlocked sea) as an example, but the concept is the same when applied to a country. And we find examples in print. This [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/) has twelve examples of *país interior*, from an unidentified encyclopaedia. For instance:

> O Paraguai é um ***país interior*** situado na América do Sul [Paraguay is a ***landlocked country*** in South America]

Some identified examples:

> Localizado na África central, o Ruanda é um ***país interior*** e não tem acesso imediato ao cabo de fibra submarino. [[*Perspectivas Económicas na África*, OECD, African Development Bank, 2009.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=_LUKRs5yKvcC&pg=PT94&dq=%22pa%C3%ADs%20interior%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiutrOOiNTLAhUEWhQKHcHdDbc4ChDoAQgpMAI#v=onepage&q=%22pa%C3%ADs%20interior%22&f=false) [Located in central Africa, Ruanda is a ***landlocked country***, and has no direct access to the submarine fibre cable.]
>
> Niger [...] Situaçao geográfica: ***país interior***, cortado a oeste pelo rio que lhe da o nome [[Murillo Alves da Cunha, ‎J. Michaelovitch, *Atlas Mundial*, 1968.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=pOBKAAAAYAAJ&q=%22pa%C3%ADs%20interior%22&dq=%22pa%C3%ADs%20interior%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjci6mbitTLAhWHbxQKHd4QDlY4MhDoAQhGMAg) [Niger […] Geographic situation: ***landlocked country***, crossed in the west by the river that gives the country its name]
>
> Desde a viagem de Vasco da Gama à Índia, em 1498, que se sabia que a Etiópia era um ***país interior***, onde se poderia chegar a partir de alguns portos do Mar Vermelho controlados pelos muçulmanos.   [[André Ferrand de Almeida, «Da Demanda do Preste João à Missão Jesuíta na Etiópia», *Lusitânia Sacra*, 2ª Série, Tomo XI, 1999, p.264.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=G7OwHFo6CVIC&pg=PA264&dq=%22pa%C3%ADs%20interior%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv1Oy2jNTLAhWFXRQKHU52C-U4HhDoAQgvMAM#v=onepage&q=%22pa%C3%ADs%20interior%22&f=false) [It was known since Vasco da Gama’s voyage to India in 1498 that Ethiopia was a ***landlocked country***, reachable from some Red Sea ports under Muslim control.]

Answer (score 3):

Um sinônimo para *país interior* ou *país sem acesso ao mar*, que atenderia à tradução buscada na pergunta, seria *país mediterrâneo*. "País duplamente interior" não soa muito bem, ao passo que uma tradução como "país mediterrâneo em segundo grau" me parece ser uma solução interessante.

*Encravado* é mais utilizado em relação a países cuja totalidade das fronteiras são feitas com as terras de um único país, sendo o adjetivo correspondente aos substantivos *encrave* ou *enclave* (esta última forma é mais comum que *encrave*).

- Exemplo de uso da expressão *país mediterrâneo* pode ser encontrado em trecho de "O poder absoluto do Dr. Francia", Bruno Soerensen, Arte & Ciência, 1998, que pode ser lido no Google Books: "O Paraguai, país mediterrâneo, ..."
- Usei o dicionário Priberam online como fonte para definições.

Comment: Excelente resposta, não sabia esse significado para *mediterrâneo*.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_pa%C3%ADses_sem_costa_mar%C3%ADtima) uses *encravado* in its Portuguese version for the article on *Landlocked Countries*. Strangely, it references [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=encravado) Dictionary, but there's no mention of a country without access to oceans. Priberam also does not define [encravado](https://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/Encravado) in the meaning intended by the OP.

Comment: Pode-se pensar *encravado* nesse sentido como uma extensão da aceção 4 do Michaelis (situado entre outros (prédio, terreno) sem comunicação com via pública). A Enciclopédia Fundamental Verbo, Lisbo/São Paulo, 1982, trás «o território do Lesoto encontra-se totalmente ***encravado*** na República da África do Sul».

Comment: @Jacinto, para casos de países como o Lesoto (ou o Vaticano e San Marino), existe o termo [enclave](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Enclave). Apesar de todo _enclave_ ser um _país interior_, o contrário não é verdadeiro (Mônaco, p. ex.).

Comment: Não me tinha lembrado do *enclave*, mas é verdade que um enclave pode ter costa, e não tem adjetivo correspondente. Ou mellhor, tem, é *encravado*. As duas palavras têm de certeza a mesma origem.

Comment: Os cartórios de registro de imóveis no Brasil também usam o termo encravado, para quando uma construção ou terreno fica sem via de passagem (a lei obriga portanto a dar passagem, claro). Nas leis, decretos etc, também consta esse termo.